Does the color of glass affect its index of refraction?
I've found found lots of stuff on how the color of light relates to the index of refraction while holding the refraction material constant, but I'm looking at the opposite problem: does the color of the glass change the IOR (holding the light color constant) and if so; how much?
I'd be interested in the theory for why, but a reference to a sufficiently detailed IOR table for a suitable type of glass with different concentrations of colorants would get me most of what I actually need.

(NOTE: everything below here is context, the question is the above.)
Very specifically, if a block of clear optical glass were to be surface treated by adding high concentration of typical coloration additives like nickle or iron into the existing glass (e.g. sputter some metal onto the surface and defuse it into the glass resulting in a gradient structure), would I have to take that into account with regards to internal reflections either off the original outer surface or the inner limit of the treatment? (Given the inner limit is almost certainly not sharp, it would seem like it would at most act like a gradient index lens of some sort?)
I rather suspect the answer will have a lot of "it depends", but knowing what it depends on and how much would be useful by itself.
The end goal is I'm exploring options for is how to get a totally non reflective internal surface under grazing incidence conditions and this is one of several option being considered. (Edit: I also want to block light coming from the outside, but that's a simple problem once the first is solved. E.g. a opaque metal housing would do that job and a carbon black coating on the housing surfaces would remove most of the light that escapes the optics before it gets back.)

"surface treated' ?  most treatments like this add a distinct different index material, very thin, vapor deposited, which reflects unwanted colours ... like sunglasses ... so NO.  If you mix something in the glass to absorb ... then that changes your glass ... slight ior shift likely ....

@PhysicsDave treatment not coating. My initial thought was to sputter nickel on the surface and then bake it until it defuses onto the glass (nickel makes glass brown/black) but figured I should ask this question before figuring out if that process works.


The end goal is I'm exploring options for is how to get a totally non reflective internal surface under grazing incidence conditions and this is one of several option being considered.

Addressing this part only:  You can't.  When you have light entering at grazing incidence from the outside, it will refract closer to normal to the surface when it enters the glass.  Any light inside the glass hitting the surface closer to grazing than that angle will have total internal reflection.  This will be true even if you add layers of different materials at the surface.
Farther from grazing than that angle, it is possible, but the conditions needed for that for polarization in the plane of incidence and perpendicular to the plane of incidence will be different.  You will either have to settle for no reflection for only one polarization, or solve for them both simultaneously.

Total internal reflections is a result of the change in IOR. If a layer has the exact same IOR it doesn't happen. If the layer is also highly absorbent, then it would seem an arbitrarily high percentage of light could be absorbed before the light reflects back. This question is asking if both those conditions can be accomplished by adding/defusing colorants into the existing glass surface. Or is there some reason that, even if both can be done, it still wouldn't work?

Specific Answers

does the color of the glass change the IOR (holding the light color constant)?

The color of a material seen in transmission is because specific frequencies of light are absorbed by the material. This is extinction coefficient or excitation modes. The color of a material seen in reflection is because specific frequencies of light are not reflected. This is index of refraction and extinction coefficient.

... If a block of clear optical glass were to be surface treated by adding high concentration of typical coloration additives, would I have to take that into account with regards to internal reflections either off the outer surface or the inner surface of the treatment?

Yes. If the additive becomes a substitutional or interstitial dopant, the index of refraction, extinction coefficient, and potentially also the excitation modes of the material will change. If the additive becomes a second phase, it will act as a scattering center. Think alcohol in water (homogenous dopant additive throughout material) versus oil in water (two phase dopant in background matrix).
Regardless, the coated layer will act as a second layer with a defined thickness, index of refraction, extinction coefficient, and optical excitation levels. The layer will change the refraction and reflection of light entering it from either side as well as the absorbance/transmission of light going through it. See Fresnel's and Snells' equations for calculating reflection and refraction. See formulations about extinction coefficients (leading to Beer's law) and excitation modes for calculating absorption/transmission.

The end goal is ... how to get a totally non reflective internal surface under grazing incidence conditions and this is one of several option being considered.

Basic calculations can be done at one frequency using the above mentioned formulations and the base expression that $1 = f_A + f_T + f_R$, where each fraction is for absorbance, transmission, and reflection. Since the incident angle is off-normal, you will need to consider the s and p polarization modes separately. See information about calculations of Brewster's angle as a starting point. Index of refraction, extinction coefficient, and excitation modes are all frequency (wavelength) dependent. Extensions across frequency can be done as point-by-point hand calculations. Or you can find a computer tool designed to calculate these systems effectively.

I also want to block light coming from the outside, but that's a simple problem once the first is solved.)

Your optimism may be tempered once you delve further into the exact expressions for just your basic two layer component, even at the one-frequency case, and not accounting for multiple internal reflections and/or polarization modes (especially off normal incidence).

I'd be interested in the theory for why, but a sufficiently detailed IOR table for type of glass with different concentrations of colorants would get me most of what I actually need.

The theory is above and below. If they are posted, tables of optical properties for different concentrations of different dopants in specific materials could be found in reference handbooks or in journal articles specific to the materials and methods of interest. Alternatively, you may be able to get details that are specific to your exact materials system from technical experts in companies that provide coated glass components as reflection or band pass devices.
Background
Two factor define how light travels through a material (non-vacuum). The index of refraction defines its (wave packet) speed, and the extinction coefficient defines the extent that a (wave packet) is absorbed. Both depend on frequency. A natural relationship exists to link the two factors.
The first fundamental factor to consider is the nature of the polarizable modes in the material. They include electronic or orbital modes, ionic modes, dipolar modes, and plasmon modes. Electronic is from electrons in orbitals and appears in all materials, ionic is in ionically bonded materials, dipolar is in materials with permanent dipoles, and plasmons are the free electrons in metals or semiconductors. The type and number density of polarizable modes in a material affect the index of refraction as a function of wavelength. The second fundamental factor to consider is the excitability of electronic modes at different frequencies (energies). This affects the extinction coefficient. The final factor is the degree of internal scattering from such things as microscopic or macroscopic defects.
One can selectively change the index of refraction in a specific frequency range in various ways. But ... adding color absorbers may only change the extinction coefficient at the given index of refraction and not directly affect the index of refraction.
The optical properties of interest include the reflection, absorbance, and transmission as a function of wavelength and incident angle. In studies to generate these optical properties for multi-component systems, a surface coating is generally modeled as a separate layer with its own unique index of refraction and extinction coefficient functions. The additional parameter of concern is the layer thickness.
One can create optical components with a wide range of optical properties over the input parameters of frequency or incident angle depending on coating material and coating thickness, let alone coating uniformity and interlayer roughness. To be specific, when your goal is to design a multi-layer optical component to perform in a specific manner over a specific range of input frequencies and incident angles, you must specify the exact chemical nature of each material and the thickness of each layer. The exact chemical nature includes the material type (metal, ceramic, semiconductor, polymer), its composition (number density of each component), and in some cases its structure (crystalline, glassy, or amorphous). You must also choose a model equation for each optical mode (electronic, ionic, dipolar, and plasmon) in each layer. Finally, the complexity of the modeling increases as you increase the number of layers or as you intend to tweak the input parameters to the models (e.g. change how the index of refraction varies for a standard ionic material to allow for dopants). For this reason, when your goal is at least some semblance of accurate prediction, you typically must use sophisticated software packages that are designed to handle the formulations and inputs.
As a caveat to this, all modeling goes sideways when you compare their ideal results to systems with real factors such as roughness or gradual composition changes at the interlayers as well as granular versus perfectly crystalline materials as the components.
A summary recommendation is to review for textbooks on how the nature of materials (chemistry and structure) affect optical properties and to search for on-line software packages to model optical properties of materials in devices.

Could you be more specific? -- Everything before your last sentence basically only confirms I'm asking the correct questions and that the answer is some kind of "maybe" or "it-depends" without saying what it depend on, which is the question I actually asked. Your last sentence, while useful, would also be of similar use for virtually every STEM question (and many others) on the internet. Are there terms I should be researching within the general field of optical coatings?

@BCS I've updated with specifics. Start with a textbook on the nature of materials to learn covalent, ionic, and metallic bonding as well as crystalline, glassy, and amorphous structures. Move to a textbook on electrical / optical properties of materials in response to oscillating electric fields to learn electronic, ionic, molecular, and plasmon modes. Finally, move to a textbook on modeling optical properties for multi-layer optical devices to learn how matrix equations include index of refraction, extinction coefficient, and layer thickness to propagate waves from input to output. Enjoy!

I'm not seeing anything added that is more useful to me than "become an expert in designing optical systems" which I already know would work. I'm asking this question in the hopes that someone who has already done that can save me a few decades or work.

@BCS OK. Specific answers are added.

Your answers seems to be to a different question (one I can solve on my own) than I'm asking. --- Re: "The coating will act as an additive layer with a [...] index of refraction [...]" that takes as already given some known IOR, where as I'm asking about what the IOR will be. Also, I'm assuming that the surface treatment will not coat, but rather dope the original material of the optics themselves. In the minimal case, that will act exactly like the original surface, because it is the original surface.

@BCS Your improved explanation of how the layer might be created has improved my understanding of your questions.

If you don't have resource that answer the question I'm asking, don't feel obligated to post. Your answer still boils down to "go look up the answer yourself". What I'm hoping for would be more along the line of a reference to an IOR table or parametric model. I looked for such data before posting and haven't found it; maybe I'm looking in the wrong paces, maybe the effect is too small to be interesting (good!) or maybe something else I haven't thought of. -- (Clearly scattering would be counter productive, that's one of the reason nickle is one of the first dopents I'm considering.)

@BCS The goalpost moves each time you repost and re-edit. Have you contacted companies that provide optical coatings on glasses within the materials specifications of your system?

I'm starting to regret mention what I'd use the answer for as it seems to have confused the issue about what I actual want to learn. Lets start over: Ignoring everything else here, pretending you have never seen any of it, an answer that isn't directly applicable to the following question, isn't what I'm asking for: "How much, if at all, does the addition of metal ion colorants to common optical glasses change their IOR?"
